# Friend operator in template struct raises redefinition error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

Consider this code:

```
template<typename T,typename K>
struct A{

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, K x) { 
      // Do some output 
      return out; 
   }

};

int main(){
   A<int,int> i;
   A<double,int> j;
}
```

It does not compile, because the two instantiations of A instantiate the `operator<<` two times with the same signature, so I receive this error:

```
test.cpp:26:25: error: redefinition of ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, int)’
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, K x) { return out; }
                         ^
test.cpp:26:25: error: ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, int)’ previously defined here
```

How to fix this? How can I have a friend operator in a template, when that operator *might* have the same signature for two different instantiations? How can I solve this without triggering a redefinition error?

Comment: Do you need `T` in definition of `operator<<`?

Comment: int already works with `operator<<`. It's up to each class to provide a suitable `operator<<`

Comment: I do not really understand why you implement `operator<<` for K, and especially why you need it to be friends with an (almost) unrelated class `A<T,K>`. And as Neil said, it's up to `K` to provide an implementation of the operator, and `int` already has one.

Comment: You don't. You define in your class operations that relate to the class, not its templated parameters.

Comment: I agree with CashCow here. In your example, the stream inserter really doesn't need to be a friend to `struct A`. It might need to be a friend of `K` but it doesn't need to know anything about the internals of `A`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really see any use in declaring a friend like this, nevertheless this is how you can do it:

```
template<typename T, typename K>
struct A{
  template<typename L>
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, L const &x);
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, T const &x) {
  // ... 
  return out;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://ideone.com/ccimDR)

Edit:

Another option probably closer to what you want will be:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, T const &x);

template<typename T, typename K>
struct A{
  friend std::ostream& operator<<<K>(std::ostream& out, K const &x);
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, T const &x) { 
  // ...
  return out;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc32c2b86d4360c9)

But really not sure why you want this. IMHO your design has serious flaws.

Comment: Your answer makes no real sense to do either. Have no idea why it got 7 upvotes

Comment: @CashCow Well, it doesn't make much more sense but answers the question / solves the problem: the friend operator is a template *within* a class (template instance). Hence multiple definitions *are allowed*.

Comment: The friend operator here does not define anything that relates to the class at all. How is cout << 3 related to A<double, int> ? Even more so in your answer is it related to A<double, std::string> ?

Comment: @CashCow The real question is why anyone would want to do something like this. Do you see any real uses in this design?

Comment: I cannot see what the user is trying to achieve at all. Assuming A has some private members (if not you don't need to make anything a friend) you can declare the friendship to grant access to streaming functions of a parameter type or all streaming functions. Trying to implement the stream though is totally faulty and out of the scope of the class.

Comment: Your answer grants access to A<X,Y> to operator<<(ostream&, L> for any type L, his gives it only to streaming an Y.

Comment: @CashCow I've already provided a second option that overcomes this, but really there's no use in such a design.

Comment: It compiles, but if you try to use it you get a stack overflow since you recourse cout << t into cout << t itself. It can work oly for types like int, where your template is not used since a specific << for int already exist. (so ... it works if not used!)

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Well spotted, this is attributed to the recursive call `return (out << x);`. Corrected that.

Comment: `friend std::ostream& operator<<<K>(std::ostream& out, K const &x);` can be `friend std::ostream& operator<<<>(std::ostream& out, K const &x);`

Answer (score 3):

Your question is faulty in the following way.

Assuming it's a stub and your class has something private such that it needs to declare a friend, the purpose of doing so is that the friend is external to the class itself but has access to what is private within it.

In your case you are declaring streaming functions of a parameter as a friend. That is fine. It means if someone creates a class `Bar` and wants to define how a `Bar` is streamed their implementation may access anything in `A<T,Bar>` for any type `T`.

The clashing of your template with `operator<<( ostream&, int)` is not actually a problem as the compiler knows which one to pick. It will always pick the exact match non-templated over the templated one. Your problem is that you have 2 templated ones and the compiler cannot pick between them because they are both equally valid.

Maybe something like this is what you are really trying to achieve

```
template< typename X, typename Y >
struct A
{
   friend void a_print( std::ostream& Y const & ); // foo external function with Y as parameter, can access this
};

std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & out, Bar const& bar )
{
   a_print( out, bar );
   return out;
}

void a_print( Bar const& bar, std::ostream & out )
{
   // implement and call private members of A<Foo, Bar>
   return out;
}
```

You could make the streaming template a friend and implement the one for Bar to stream using a specific implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Factor the method out to a base class:

```
template <typename K>
struct ABase
{
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, K x) { 
      // Do some output 
      return out; 
   }
};

template <typename T,typename K>
struct A : public ABase<K>
{};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream an `A` object, the proper signature should have been

```
template<typename T,typename K>
struct A{

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const A& x) { 
      // Do some output 
      return out; 
   }

};
```

taking an `A<T,K>` for which you can access private members, not a `K`.

If there is no way to get an A from K (and cannot be if `K` is `int`), making `<<(ostream&,K)` a friend of `A` gives no benefits.

Comment: Does your declaration work? Maybe the standard has changed, to get that to work previously you had to forwardly declare the template and use template<> in the friend declaration

Comment: In A name scope, << is not a template. May be a old compiler need A<T,K> instead of just A. But having template<> in front or the function redefined outside is not necessary (unless the function is a fried of many..., so playing in a neutral filed sounds better). In that case you declare the friend and template<> and implement it as template<class T, class K> outside of A's body

Comment: I remember in the past I needed to do: friend template<> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const A& );